# why do we have to pass a pointer to a pointer to cudaMalloc

Tags: cuda

The following codes are widely used for GPU global memory allocation:

```
float *M;
cudaMalloc((void**)&M,size);
```

I wonder why do we have to pass a pointer to a pointer to cudaMalloc, and why it was not designed like:

```
float *M;
cudaMalloc((void*)M,size);
```

Thanks for any plain descriptions!

Comment: cudaMalloc needs to *return* a pointer, so you need to pass a pointer to the pointer

Answer (score 6):

`cudaMalloc` needs to write the value of the pointer to `M` (not `*M`), so `M` must be passed by reference.

Another way would be to return the pointer in the classic `malloc` fashion. Unlike `malloc`, however, `cudaMalloc` returns an error status, like all CUDA runtime functions.

Comment: Martin James: The reason for not returning the pointer like malloc is because all cuda runtime functions need to return a error status. To comply to that, the pointer is taken as a first parameter instead.

Comment: ...and thanks to Jared for editing for clarification and accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the need in a little more detail:

Before the call to `cudaMalloc`, `M` points... anywhere, undefined. After the call to `cudaMalloc` you want a valid array to be present at the memory location where it points at. One could naïvely say "then just allocate the memory at this location", but that's of course not possible in general: the undefined address will normally not even be inside valid memory. `cudaMalloc` need to be able to *choose* the location. But if the pointer is called by value, there's no way to tell the caller where.

In C++, one could make the signature

```
template<typename PointerType>
cudaStatus_t cudaMalloc(PointerType& ptr, size_t);
```

where passing `ptr` by reference allows the function to change the location, but since `cudaMalloc` is part of the CUDA C API this is not an option. The only way to pass something as modifiable in C is to pass a pointer to it. And the object is itself a pointer what you need to pass is a pointer to a pointer.